# Testing HDFS replication?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Suppose I'm writing some data to HDFS with dfs.replication set to 3.

Is there any way I could fetch all 3 replicas from different datanodes and compare them?

I guess I could just kill the other datanodes before reading the file from HDFS, but is there any elegant way?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but, out of curiosity, why do you expect the replicas to be different and not identical to each other?

Comment: Since you asked, I've replaced HDFS's default write procedure and I want to test it with more than 1 replication.

Comment: Get the destination data node hostname details & location/path where data is written from the namenode log.